# how to start rails app at localhost:3000/appname

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, web-deployment

I wonder whether there are any `app-level` configurations to run deploy rails on`localhost:3000/appname`. Please, can anyone help?

Comment: Just run `rails s` in the project folder. If it's not finding the project automatically you could run `bundle exec rails s`. But it isn't then on the sub-path `appname` but rather on `localhost:3000` directly.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is I want to know a way to deploy my app at localhost:3000/appname (by running the command "rails s" in the project folder).

Answer (score -1):

You can use `rails s -p 3001` if you want to run more than one Rails app at one time.

Just go ahead to `localhost:3001` in your browser.

Comment: This isn't what OP has asked.

Comment: Actually, I got a redirecting problem when config nginx to my app, but the problem will be solved by deploying on localhost:3000/appname. That why I need to ask this question.

Comment: Please be specific next time. Don't waste people time.